# How do you split an array column and group it with the equivalent rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a DataFrame which has an array in one of the columns, some of the elements of this array correspond to elements in other rows, other don't.

Is there an easy way that I can split the array and add it to the columns that already have some entries, and create new columns for the rest?

Here's an example:

```
Count     Tag    Tag_Array
  2        A        [A]
  3        B        [B]
  8        C        [C]
  4        -        [A, C, D]
  3        E        [E]
```

And what I'd like to do is get the following dataframe:

```
Count     Tag    
  6        A
  3        B
 12        C
  4        D
  3        E
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `pandas explode` could help here

Comment: Why row 4 change to D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`explode` then do the `groupby` with `sum`

```
df.explode('Tag_Array').groupby('Tag_Array').Count.sum().reset_index()
Out[237]: 
  Tag_Array  Count
0         A      6
1         B      3
2         C     12
3         D      4
4         E      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) then [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum)

```
df.explode(column='Tag_Array').groupby('Tag_Array', as_index=False)['Count'].sum()
```

---

```
  Tag_Array  Count
0         A      6
1         B      3
2         C     12
3         D      4
4         E      3
```